# Display user content

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (! isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
    $query = "
        SELECT 
            username, first_name, last_name, gender, birthdate, city, state, picture
        FROM 
            mismatch_user 
        WHERE 
            user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
}
```

this is the code that I am using to display the information for the user logged in. how would I code it so that you can view other profiles within the same profile.php script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the problem is. What about the following query?

```
$query = "SELECT username, first_name, last_name, gender, birthdate, city, state, picture FROM mismatch_user WHERE user_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user_id']) . "'";
```

Please note also that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Always use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape user input sent to the database.

Comment: so like this  if (!isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT username, first_name, last_name, gender, birthdate, city, state, picture FROM mismatch_user WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
  }
  else {
    $query = "SELECT username, first_name, last_name, gender, birthdate, city, state, picture FROM mismatch_user WHERE user_id = '" . $_GET['user_id'] . "'";
  }

Comment: @mattmorris you do not escape $_GET['user_id'] as middus suggested in his answer. This leaves your code vulnarable to SQL injections, which is a serious security issue, for details see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Comment: well, yes, but you need to make sure `$_GET['user_id']` is an integer or use mysql_real_escape_string on it. It's a practice that I and others here, can not emphasize enough. Make it a habit to always make sure that stuff that goes into a SQL query is escaped: [php manual on SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $_GET['user_id'] will have a value in the case you want to see the profile of another user, and that if no user_id is specified the profile of the logged in user should be displayed:

```
isset($_GET['user_id']) ?
    $user_id = (int) $_GET['user_id'] :
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query = "
    SELECT 
        username, first_name, last_name, gender, birthdate, city, state, picture
    FROM 
        mismatch_user 
    WHERE 
        user_id = '" . $user_id . "'";
```

The cast to an int for the $_GET assignment will prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Casting will work for integers (I assume like you that the id will be an integer), but not for strings. That's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Yes, if you cast a string to an int, the value will be 0, unless the string starts with digits or whitespace followed by digits, in those cases the string will be cast to the integer represented by the digits at the start of the string.